# jquery fileDownload library, done event never called

Tags: jquery

I use [fileDownload](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) for calling my excel export page. it works for the download. but the "done" event is never called.

```
$.fileDownload('ExportExcel.aspx')
.done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
.fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```

Comment: Have you tried `successCallback` handler instead of `done()`?

Comment: I tried, but still nothing. the callback is never call. no error or complete. prepreCallback working.

Comment: I tried IE TAb for firefox. I got an error for calling about:security_plugin-container.exe

Comment: I think I will look at something else then filDownload

Comment: I tried failMessageHtml, the message is always visible. dont close after success.